# Developing Laravel in running Docker Container

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-artisan

Docker newbie here and I don't understand how it all works together. How do I develop in the container?  Or do I need to do development and then build and run the container as two separate actions?

I created a Laravel 10 app in ~/source/mediacenter.  I dockerized it with this Dockerfile, built it and started it.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-cli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 3100
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

I can access it from localhost:3100.

Now how do I make a change to my Laravel code and see it work?  Changes are in my /source/mediacenter directory but code is running in /var/www/html.  If I docker exec into the container and run artisan (create a new model for instancde), those changes happen in /var/www/html/ and not my source code.

Does this mean I need to develop and run locally and when I am happy with it, build the image and container to deploy wherever I want?  Or, is there a trick that can let me develop and test within the running container?  I did spend an hour searching for solutions but am probably not asking the right question.

Comment: 2 things: 1) if you really want to use your own docker stuff, then make a volume. Bind your local working directory to the path inside the container. The changes made locally will then be reflected inside the container. No need to copy stuff. 2) use Laravel sail. Publish its vendor files, `sail up` and you're done

Comment: Agreed with @UnderDog.  You have to make volume and bind host directory with container directory, then either way any changes would be synchronized.

Comment: FWIW I tend to recommend doing most development work locally, with native host tools with good IDE support, and only bringing Docker into the picture for data stores, integration testing, and deployment, but opinions vary heavily on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker-compose map your changes in running containers.

for example, your docker file must be bellow:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd soap

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Install app dependency
RUN mkdir /app

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /app/storage \
        /app/bootstrap/cache

RUN php artisan optimize && \
    php artisan key:generate && \
    php artisan config:cache&& \
    php artisan route:cache

VOLUME /app

USER $user

VOLUME /app
```

And your `docker-compose.yml` file like bellow:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: laravel
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: laravel-app
    container_name: laravel-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
```

Now every change can when you did map into container

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about docker and you wish to focus on development first, you may use [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation) instead.

Command:

`curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`

Where `example-app` is the root project folder.

This will download a basic PHP docker image with a default Laravel project for you. Running `./vendor/bin/sail up` will build/start the container.

You can update the code inside `example-app` and this will be reflected in your project.

Sail also comes with composer and node/npm.

Commands:

```
# artisan:
./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
# composer:
./vendor/bin/sail composer install
# npm:
./vendor/bin/npm install
```

If you are in ubuntu, you can create an alias so that you can shorten `./vendor/bin/sail` to `sail`

Comment: I think you can skip on adding the `artisan` command when using sail.